# Gunicorn --preload option is causing workers to hang?

Tags: flask, gunicorn, preload

We have a flask app that uses a lot of memory for ML models, and I'm trying to reduce the memory footprint by using gunicorn's `preload` option, but when I add the `--preload` flag, and deploy that (with `-w 4`, to a docker container running on GKE), it will handle just a few requests, and then hang until it times out, at which point gunicorn will start another worker to replace it and the same thing will happen. It's not clear yet how many requests each worker will process before hanging (possibly just 1... possibly a few)

The timeout is over 10 minutes, so it seems to be hanging indefinitely.

This does not happen at all if I remove the `--preload` flag.

What is it about the `--preload` flag that could be causing the workers to hang indefinitely?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer for this, but I believe it must have something to do with code that is not thread-safe.  Certain endpoints work fine with this option enabled, but other endpoints hang, possibly due to some non-threadsafe code.  I haven't narrowed down the bug, but thought this might be helpful for someone else getting a similar issue, since the resources I've consulted don't mention much about the possibility of code not being threadsafe.

Comment: Did you find what was the underlying issue? I'm experiencing possibly related problem where my variables are not initialized possibly because they are initialized in a separate thread.

Comment: I never figured out the root of this problem.  I still believe it was just some kind of thread-safety issue in the code, but I didn't look into it enough to discover what.